# GRPC Java - Prevent Memory Leaks

Tags: java, multithreading, grpc, grpc-java

I'm trying to prevent GRPC from using more than one thread per channel. To do this I setup a single thread executor with the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3 * numFaults + 1; i++) {
            //One thread for each channel
            ManagedChannel channel = NettyChannelBuilder
                    .forAddress(host, port + i + 1)
                    .usePlaintext()
                    .executor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
                    .build();
```

I then create an asyn stub for each channel.

However, this doesn't seem to be working as I am still spawning way too many threads in my program, eventually running out of memory.

Should i pass the executor to the stub instead? Or is there something fundamentally wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "using more than one thread per channel" but each channel only has a single threaded executor.

Comment: yes but when I see the thread usage on my machine I see that it is still spawning many threads

Answer (score 1):

The additional spawned threads are probably EventLoop threads (by default it can create up to # of core threads). There is an option to provide EventLoopGroupin NettyChannelBuilder. To use this API you also need to set ChannelType. [EventLoopGroup](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/EventLoopGroup.html) and [Channel](https://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/Channel.html) Type are from [netty](https://github.com/netty/netty) see linked javadoc for more details if you are interested.

you can use Epoll if on linux otherwise using NIO is current gRPC behavior. Below example is using NIO.
All the network events are happening on the event loop thread, therefore using less threads can affect overall performance dramatically (depends on how channel is used). you can also consider using [directExecutor](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#directExecutor()) and allocate more threads for the EventLoopGroup.

```
NioEventLoopGroup sharedEventLoopGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(numThread);
ManagedChannel channel = NettyChannelBuilder
    .forAddress(host, port + i + 1)
    .usePlaintext()
    .channelType(NioSocketChannel.class)
    .eventLoopGroup(sharedEventLoopGroup)
    .executor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
    .build();
```

Comment: forget to mention that it is rare to see # threads causes out of memory unless there are too many threads. If you are running out of memory, analyze heap dump to see what is there. it maybe due to leak or maybe not. also, please modify the title since this is not memory leak issue.